# Force android default browser to redraw blurry images as clear images?

Tags: javascript, android, css

No one is answering this particular question

[CSS position:fixed causes blurry images in Android Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343897/css-positionfixed-causes-blurry-images-in-android-browsers)

So I'm going to ask for something specific that might help me out.

Is there some kind of re-draw/re-render function in javascript (webkit), or some kind of css equivalent, that might force an image to refresh itself?  Something that will force Android default browsers to redraw blurry images into clear images, as described by the problem in my original question?

The cause of the image blurriness is a combination of `position:fixed` and stretching/compressing the image.

Comment: Did you consider lazy loading images on document.ready event ? I think it should work if position:fixed is the culprit.

Comment: @tea_totaler Indeed I did try it and no effect.  The logo still appears blurry when loaded in 10 seconds later via javascript.  I even replace the logo with an iframe that points to another web page of images, and all those images were blurry too.

Comment: I am sorry for making another wild guess but have considered making setting those images as background-image of the div. for the sake if semantics you can put 1*1 transparent px in your img tag.

Comment: yup tried that as well.  Same blurriness issue