# alternative to z-index and position:fixed issue in android default browser

Tags: android, css, z-index, css-position

My question is related to this problem: [Blurry images on stock android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309857/blurry-images-on-stock-android-browser/16787267#comment25147695_16787267)

Except I have a more specific issue.

Basically I have blurry image issue in Android default browser.  If I have a `position:fixed` element with `z-index:20`, then ANY OTHER element with a z-index greater than or equal to 20 that also has an image (either a decedent img element or element with background image) will also appear blurry.  In other words, the maximum z-index value that will ensure crisp image must be less than the z-index of any position:fixed element on the page. Here's example code to demonstrate what I mean:

Demo Url: http://jl.evermight.net/blurryposition/z-index.html

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }
a {
      background-image:url(logotest_big.jpg);
      background-size:60%;
            display:block;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
      } 
  </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top-nav-container"
        style="
    position:fixed;
        top:0px; 
    z-index:20;
        ">
      <a></a>
        </div>
        <div id="top-nav-container-2"
        style="
    position:absolute;
    top:300px; 
    z-index:40;
        ">
            <a></a>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

The code demonstrates a blurry image.  But if you change the z-indexes such that position:fixed element is greater than the position:absolute element, the position:absolute element will have a crisp image.

How do I correct this problem such that i can have non-blurry images with z-index greater than the z-index of a position:fixed element?

This only happens on some default android browsers.  in my case, Android 4.0 on Galaxy note v1.

Comment: This z-index talk sounds like nonsense to me. Have you tried to use larger image and `background-size`? I saw blurry images only when using non-optimized images on high pixel density screens.