# High resolution images blurry on Android but not iPhones using Lightview modals

Tags: android, html, css, image, modal-dialog

I have images in `.png` and `.jpg` displayed inside [Lightview](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/) modals that turn out blurry on Android phones. iPhones are unaffected. The size of the modals and images are being automatically set by the view port size.

**HTML (Lightview builds it dynamically)**

```
<div class="lv_window">
   <div class="lv_content">
      <div class="lv_content_wrapper">
         <img class="lv_content_image" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.lv_window {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display:block;
  /* width, height, top, and left are dynamically set depending on viewport */
}
.lv_content {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('somegif.gif');
  display: block;
  /* width, height, top, and left are dynamically set depending on viewport */
}
.lv_content .lv_content_wrapper {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;  
}
.lv_content_image {
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  /* width and height are dynamically set depending on viewport in px */
}
```

I'm using MVC to give each image a source (`src`) because I have a different image depending upon what state they pick in the select. Otherwise, all CSS and HTML is created by Lightview.

I have looked through other posts like [Blurry images on stock android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309857/blurry-images-on-stock-android-browser/16787267) because my issue is very similar, but I do not have any z-index or `position: fixed` set anywhere. My issue is produced on the Android default browser in version `4.0.4`, `4.1.2`, and `4.2.2` on both the `Samsung Galaxy S3` and `S4` (these details given to me by our testers).

I have tried overriding the Lightview CSS float to none for the class `.lv_content_image` and still no change in image quality.

I will post an example image when I can.

Comment: What devices are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4

Answer (score 0):

This is [a strange bug](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/630385-galaxy-s3-loads-pictures-low-quality-in-browser-apps-help-plz.html) with S3. Set these **both** on image tag would do the trick:

```
opacity: 0.999999;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Unfortunately, the exact same method cause error on S4, and S3 and S4 have the same screen width/height, 320×640. So instead of writing pixel-accurate `@media` stylesheets, use:

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
window.platform = {
    ...
    isS3: ua.match(/gt\-i9300/i) !== null
}
if (platform.isS3) {
    $('img').css{
        'opacity': 0.9999,
        'webkitBackfaceVisibility': 'hidden'
    }
}
```